# VBA loop columns and rows for number

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure this is explained somewhere but I can't seem to find out what I should search for.

I'm writing some code that lets the user input a number and the code should then do certain tasks that number of times. I only want to do this task to be done at a maximum of columns per row (lets say 10). Then start at the next row.

Right now I have a nested loop but I can't find a way to make it work with only one loop, instead I've had to create one loop for all rows that's complete (10 columns long) and then a single loop for the last row.

```
For i = 0 to numberOfCompleteRows
    For j = 0 to numberOfColumns
        tasks(j,i)
    next j
next i

For x = 0 to numberOfColumnsAtLastRow
    tasks(x,i+1)
next i
```

Is there a better way to do this?

(Sorry if there's some small errors in here, my actual code is not written for excel so didn't find a reason to post it as it was, tried to make it as standard as possible.)

Comment: Might depend on what `tasks` does, but in general if you're doing a task for every cell in a range you can declare your range and then do a `for each cell in range` loop

Comment: In addition to @jamheadart, please note that `0 to numberOfCompleteRows` is actually `numberOfCompleteRows`+1 iterations. Same for `numberOfColumns`

Answer (score 0):

If you loop from `1` to the `TotalNumberOfRows`, then the current column calculates as

```
CurrentColumn = (iRow - 1) \ NumberOfRowsPerColumn + 1
```

and the current row calculates as

```
CurrentRow = iRow - NumberOfRowsPerColumn * (CurrentColumn - 1)
```

> Note that I used the [\ Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/backslash-operator) which is actually used to divide
>   two numbers and return an integer result and no normal division that
>   would use the normal [/ Operatior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/forwardslash-operator) and return a floating-point
>   result.

So you end up with something like

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteNumbersColumnWise()
    Const TotalNumberOfRows As Long = 45
    Const NumberOfRowsPerColumn As Long = 10

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To TotalNumberOfRows
        Dim CurrentColumn As Long
        CurrentColumn = (iRow - 1) \ NumberOfRowsPerColumn + 1

        Dim CurrentRow As Long
        CurrentRow = iRow - NumberOfRowsPerColumn * (CurrentColumn - 1)

        Cells(CurrentRow, CurrentColumn).Value = iRow
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

To get the following output

[image]